# How should I index view content with Elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, elasticsearch

I have a controller that displays several views, but is not backed by a model, these views are simply rendered as **html** from the erb.

What I need to do is get the text from these views indexed in **Elasticsearch**, but I've come up against a lack of related documentation.

One additional complicating factor is that the views are translated, so they do not contain their text directly.

What should I do to get these pages indexed and searchable? And how should I maintain the index since I can't rely on activerecord callbacks?

Comment: you could think about some web crawler, like nutch or some river plugin for ES like this - https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-river-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution based on the idea of scraping the site:

in the WelcomeController:

```
format.json { render json: {body:view_to_text(view), title:@title, url:request.original_url.gsub(/\.json$/,'')} }
...
def view_to_text(view)
  html = render_to_string view, layout: false, formats: :html
  strip_tags(html).strip.gsub(/^[\s]+/,'').squeeze("\n")
end
```

and in the rake task:

```
require 'open-uri'

namespace :scrape do
  desc "scrape view content and send to elasticsearch"
  task scrape: :environment do
    client = Elasticsearch::Model.client
    session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
    session.host! Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]

    Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a.select{|r| r.defaults[:controller] == 'welcome'}.map{|r| r.path.spec.to_s.gsub( /\(\.\:format\)/, '.json') }.reject{|r| '/'==r}.each_with_index{|path,i|
      session.get path
      page_string = session.response.body
      client.index  index: Rails.env, type: 'welcome', id: i, body: page_string
    }
  end

end
```